# How tracing count a frame

Tags: android, systrace

I use tracing on chrome to analyze a file captured from an android device using systrace.And I want to know how tracing count a frame and mark it to diffenrent type.I have got tracing source code in [github](https://github.com/catapult-project/catapult),but it seem don't include this function yet.

(Engish is not my native language,so there maybe many bug in here,:P)

[systrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH9ue.png)

Answer (score 0):

systrace doesn't know anything about frames.  The Android framework has explicit calls to [android.os.Trace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Trace.html) functions.

Bear in mind that the traces are only enabled if the appropriate tag is specified.  If you add your own tracing, you need to include the `--app <appname>` argument when running systrace, or you won't see them.  For an example, see [this bigflake page](http://bigflake.com/systrace/).

Comment: I have solved my problem by reading the soure code of tracing.I found a function named *pushFramesAndJudgeJank_* that count the frame status  located in tracing/tracing/extras/android/android_auditor.html.Systrace doesn't know about frames,but tracing of chromium do.Anyway,thanks for your help :)